# перенести flex элемент на новую строку

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка, flexbox

Есть flex-контейнер с flex-элементами внутри, которые расположены в колонки равной ширины. можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы первый flex-элемент располагался в строку, то есть занимал всю ширину контейнера, а остальные flex-элементы также располагались в колонки, как раньше.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-element {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-element">a</div><!-- данный блок должен растянуться на всю ширину контейнера -->
  <div class="flex-element">b</div>
  <div class="flex-element">c</div>
  <div class="flex-element">d</div>
  <div class="flex-element">e</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто задайте первому элементу `width: 100%`, а контейнеру `flex-wrap: wrap` для перевода строки. А с остальным — всё в порядке.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-element {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex-element:first-child {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-element">a</div><!-- данный блок должен растянуться на всю ширину контейнера -->
  <div class="flex-element">b</div>
  <div class="flex-element">c</div>
  <div class="flex-element">d</div>
  <div class="flex-element">e</div>
</div>
```

Результат можете увидеть тут — [пример работы с flexbox](https://codepen.io/SCAVE/pen/QZvaVK).

Comment: Скажите, а если вместо букв я вставляют контент, например, 50 слов lorem, то другие блоки тоже начинают растягиваться, занимая 100% ширины, и перестают быть колонками, даже если задать им по 25% ширины. можно это как-то решить?

Comment: все, решила, для этих блоков просто задать flex-basis: 0;